# Dealing w/ unneeded parameters in subclass? (java)

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism

For simplicity, let's say if you have 4 classes like this:

```
Dog (Interface) - has method "walk(SomeObject a, SomeOtherObj b)"
Husky - implements Dog
Chihuahua - implements Dog
DogWalker - has a variable Dog someDog, and calls the walk method
```

We want to just use the same method in DogWalker to run walk() on any kind of dog, but let's say Chihuahua only needs/uses the first parameter, while Husky needs both parameters in its walk method.

I wouldn't want to create a separate method in the interface because I just want to use the one method, but I want to just have the one method. I know I can just "ignore" the extra parameter in the Chihuahua's walk method, but is there a cleaner way to do this? I can change pretty much anything about these classes in the real code (which is not actually about dogs... ) except for the fact that I need DogWalker to be able to take in any kind of dog and call the same method regardless of the type of dog.

Any tips would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Well if you can tell us what the real code looks like you could change the design, it depends: if your two methods are `increment(Arg a)` and `add(Arg a, Arg b)` it would be better to have separate interfaces as Jim Garrison said in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are legitimately two different `walk` methods with different parameter lists, and one applies to a subset then the hierarchy is wrong.

You need two interfaces `Walkable1` and `Walkable2` (made up names, use better names in "real life"); then dogs that use the first `walk` method implement one interface, and dogs needing the second `walk` use the second interface.  If a dog can implement both `walk` methods, it implements both interfaces.